# I can snooze Inbox by Gmail messages until "someday". When is that?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I can now snooze messages until "someday" but when does that day arrive? I'm afraid that it will either be a random day in the future or some other queue for me to (forget to) triage and neglect.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Short answer**: Never. It is just a queue that you'll need to review, eventually.

**Long answer**:

Quoted from [Inbox Support Page](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6067583?hl=en)

> Choose the **Someday** option under Snooze for emails or reminders
>   that you might want to get back to, but aren't sure when. You can go
>   back through your Someday list later and decide what to do with them.
>
> You can see everything in your Someday list by going to the main menu
>   Main menu and choosing **Snoozed**. The Someday section is toward the
>   bottom.
>
> Your email or reminder will stay in Snoozed until you move it
>   yourself. You can mark it done, move it to your inbox with pin, or
>   choose a different snooze option.

Comment: this should actually be a random-ish rainy morning, in which a rainbow would be visible and we'd be in a free day at home.

Comment: Agreed. It isn't really "Snoozed" as I understand it, if I never go into my Snoozed section. @cregox